# How to Get the MAX Time Difference Between Any 2 Consecutive Rows Per Value?

Tags: t-sql, ssms

How could I pull the maximum CreateDT difference between any two consecutive rows/[Position], per CODE, based on the CTE below:

```
WITH OccDiff AS
    (
        SELECT 
            CODE
            , CreateDT
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY CreateDT DESC) Position FROM Occs
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can we use LAG/LEAD instead?

```
SELECT MAX(diff_sec) FROM
(
  SELECT 
    DATEDIFF(
        SECOND,  
        CreateDT,
        LEAD(CreateDT) OVER(PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY CreateDT) --next row's createdt
    ) as diff_sec
  FROM Occs
)x
```

LEAD will choose the next CreateDT (next defined by "the row that has the same code and the temporally first greater CreateDt after the current row's CreateDT") relative to the current row. DATEDIFF gets the difference in seconds (choose a suitable time frame). It needs wrapping up in an subquery (or CTE if you prefer) because window function LEAD cannot appear inside a MAX

It's maybe not particularly useful, of course.. Perhaps add in the code too:

```
SELECT x.code, MAX(x.diff_sec) FROM
(
  SELECT 
    code,
    DATEDIFF(
        SECOND,  
        CreateDT,
        LEAD(CreateDT) OVER(PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY CreateDT) --next row's createdt
    ) as diff_sec
  FROM Occs
)x
GROUP BY x.code
```