# How to SELECT the MAX Time Difference Between Any 2 Consecutive Rows Per Value?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Just had a user [answer this correctly for TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58309669/how-to-get-the-max-time-difference-between-any-2-consecutive-rows-per-value), but wondering how best to achieve this now in SQL Developer/PLSQL seeing as there is no DATEDIFF function.

Table I want to query on has some 'CODE' values, which can naturally have multiple primary key records ('OccsID') in a table 'Occs'. There is also a datetime column called 'CreateDT' for each OccsID.

Just want to find the maximum possible time variance between any 2 consecutive rows in 'Occs', per 'CODE'.

Answer (score 0):

If you subtract the "next" date and "this" date (using the `LEAD` analytic function), you'll get the date difference. Then fetch the maximum difference per `code`. Something like this:

```
with diff as
  (select occsid, 
          code, 
          nvl(lead(createdt) over (partition by code order by createdt), createdt) - createdt date_diff
   from test
  )
select code, 
       max(date_diff)
from diff
group by code;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this T-SQL version works for you (from the prior question)

```
SELECT x.code, MAX(x.diff_sec) FROM
(
  SELECT 
    code,
    DATEDIFF(
        SECOND,  
        CreateDT,
        LEAD(CreateDT) OVER(PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY CreateDT) --next row's createdt
    ) as diff_sec
  FROM Occs
)x
GROUP BY x.code
```

The simplest option is just to subtract the two dates to get a difference in days.  You can then multiply to get the difference in hours, minutes, or seconds

```
SELECT x.code, MAX(x.diff_day), MAX(x.diff_sec)
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    code,
    CreateDT -
        LEAD(CreateDT) OVER(PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY CreateDT) as diff_day,
    24*60*60* (CreateDT -
        LEAD(CreateDT) OVER(PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY CreateDT)) as diff_sec

  FROM Occs
)x
GROUP BY x.code
```